# How many distinct codes of this specific form are there?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A coded message from a CIA operative to his Russian
KGB counterpart is to be sent in the form Q4ET,
where the first and last entries must be consonants; the
second, an integer 1 through 9; and the third, one of the six
vowels. How many different ciphers can be transmitted?

The answer i've obtained was 810 possible combinations. 
810 is wrong

new answer is 18 x 10^(3) possible ways since at each section of the message
20 consonants for the first
9 numbers for the second
5 letters for the third
and 20 consonants for the fourth
multiplied gave 18 x 10^(3)

Comment: How did you get 810?

Comment: Your edit, you say "*5 letters for the third*".  Why five?  Did the problem not define the number of vowels to be **six**?  The vowels are `A` `E` `I` `O` `U` and sometimes `Y`.  In this case since the problem says "six vowels" so that implies that you have **six** choices for the third.

Answer (score 4):

How many consonants are there?

> Since the problem seems to treat it as six vowels and there are 26 letters overall, there are then $20$ consonants.

How many vowels are there?

> There are $6$ vowels.

How many integers from $1$ to $9$ are there?

> There are $9$ of them.

---

How many choices then do we have for the first part of the cipher?  For the second?  For the third?  For the fourth?

What do you know about the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) (also called the multiplication principle)?

> By multiplying the number of choices available for each step (what is the first, what is the second, etc...) you get the total number of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost been 4 years since you asked the question. Somebody should give the sarcasm a rest and write a final answer...

1st entry: 20 ways to choose the consonant
2nd entry: 9 ways to choose the number
3rd entry: 6 ways to choose the vowel
4th entry: 20 ways to choose the consonant

$20*9*6*20 = 21,600$ possible ciphers

Comment: I don't know why you perceived anything else here as *sarcasm*... but one of the first things you learn in a course on how to teach is that it is in many instances better to give a hint and a leading answer than a full complete answer.  See [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28969/is-it-acceptable-to-leave-hints-as-answers?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10650/old-questions-with-hint-only-answers-can-we-provide-whole-answers?rq=1) among others.

Comment: Any teacher/professor who replies in the following sarcastic/condescending manner should take a hard look at what they're doing for a living:  "Your edit, you say "5 letters for the third". Why five? Did the problem not define the number of vowels to be six? The vowels are A E I O U and sometimes Y. In this case since the problem says "six vowels" so that implies that you have six choices for the third."

Comment: Had it been in person and the person was sure to respond, I would have stopped after asking "why five?"  After having seen the attempt and seen that they used five instead of six it became clear that was the only error and reason why they got the wrong answer as they otherwise performed the problem correctly.  Since this was not in person, I would have finished the line of thought to remind them why it should be six instead.  It was not meant to be sarcastic.  It was meant to point out the exact error made and reason why it was an error.